# How to search table associations using Sunspot/Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am very new to Sunspot/Solr and I am facing problems in getting a fulltext search to work on my website. Please find the code below:

/models/product.rb

```
attr_accessible :category_id, :title, :description
belongs_to :category

searchable do 
  text :title, :description
end
```

/models/category.rb

```
has_many :products
```

/controllers/categoriescontroller.rb

```
def show
  @category = Category.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  @search = @category.products.solr_search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @products = @search.results
end
```

/views/categories/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag @category, :method => :get do %>
   <p>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   </p>
<%end%>
```

I want to search the products that belong to a particular category. For example, if the category in the params is :fiction , I want to limit my search results to the products that are under that category. However , with the above code if I search, say 'lost' , I get all the products matching 'lost' under all categories. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it ater reading the sunspot wiki. In categoriescontroller.rb

```
if(params[:search] != nil)
    @search = Product.solr_search do
      with :category_id, Category.find_by_slug!(params[:id]).id
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @products = @search.results
  else
    @products = @category.products
end
```